# "\n" doesn't create new line in r plot when imported from excel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an excel file that I'm using as a driver file to create lots of figures. The excel file has columns like "group," "percent," and "label," where I use annotate to add the labels on various points of the figure.

For some reason though when I add "\n" to the label in the excel file, R does not create a new line at that point. In the below example I'm using the same text for two labels, but in one case I pull the label from excel, and in that case there is no new line.

How can I add a new line to a label that comes from excel?

```
library(ggplot2)                        #used to make figures
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)                         #import excel files

test <- "this is a really long sentence that has one \n line break that is kind of near the middle."
test2 <- read_excel("mwe.xlsx")
## the excel file "mwe.xlsx" has two cells filled in as below
## |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
## |test                                                                                      |
## |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## |this is a really long sentence that has one \n line break that is kind of near the middle.|
## |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

set.seed(16)
dataf <- tibble(
    percent=runif(4,0,1),
    group=c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D")
)


fig <- ggplot(data=dataf, aes(y=percent,x=group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    annotate("text",
             y=0.5,x=2,label=test)+
    annotate("text",
             y=0.25,x=3,label=test2$test)
fig
```

Comment: when you read `\n` into r it will escape it for you like this: `this is a really long sentence that has one \\n line break that is kind of near the middle.`

Comment: thanks for the info. is that a setting? or do I have to manually undo that?

Comment: hmm I am not too sure, perhaps try to save it as a text or csv file first and then see if the problem persist if so then I think you will have to do it manually or with regular expressions once the data is in r

Comment: ok thx again for the info.